# Не работаеn проверка на пустоту полей PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, sql

Я хочу проверить поле на пустоту, и если оно пустое то просто не добавляю в базу даных.

```
if(!isset($_POST["code"])) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO komentarze (nick, tresc, idPytania)
    VALUES ('$autor', '$area' ,$idPosta)";
} else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO komentarze (nick, tresc, code, idPytania)
    VALUES ('$autor', '$area', '$code' ,$idPosta)";

}
```

Что у меня не так? Почему оно все равно добавляет?

Comment: а где здесь проверка на **пустоту**?

Comment: !isset($_POST["code"])

Comment: прочтите в документации что именно проверяет isset

Comment: и как пример https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.isset.php#refsect1-function.isset-examples

Comment: empty() тебе походу надо

Comment: Но если я пишу if($_POST["code"] == null) или ($_POST["code"] == ' ') то тоже не работает

Comment: а что значит `!isset($_POST["code"] == '' ` ???

Comment: Без иссет, исправил пред комент

Comment: ещё раз..... ты прочитал описание функции isset? там есть упоминание слова "пустота"?

Comment: Хорошо, я понял что с помощью этой функции не получится проверить на пустоту, тогда как?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.empty.php

Answer (score 0):

`isset` - проверка существования переменной.
Используйте `empty` для проверки на пустоту.